# Copy JSON datas in a SQL Server table with Data Factory

Tags: json, azure-data-factory

I'm starting on Data Factory.

I'm looking to copy data from a JSON file into a SQL server table using a data copy activity.
I get my JSON data via a REST API by calling a HTTP request :
[extract of JSON 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKnWy.png)
[extract of JSON 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDVwj.png)

And I want to put the data in the following table:
[SQL Server Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPsGy.png)

I would like to create a new instance in the SQL table for each country with all its data (download, updates, etc.)

My problem is with the mapping, as it is not a simple JSON structure I can't map the data dynamically.

Could you please guide me on how to proceed to get the desired result?

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataFlow activity. In DataFlow activity use Flatten transformation.

The flatten transformation contains the following configuration settings.

**Unroll by**

Select an array to unroll. The output data will have one row per item in each array. If the unroll by array in the input row is null or empty, there will be one output row with unrolled values as null.

**Unroll root**

By default, the flatten transformation unrolls an array to the top of the hierarchy it exists in. You can optionally select an array as your unroll root. The unroll root must be an array of complex objects that either is or contains the unroll by array. If an unroll root is selected, the output data will contain at least one row per item in the unroll root. If the input row doesn't have any items in the unroll root, it will be dropped from the output data. Choosing an unroll root will always output a less than or equal number of rows than the default behavior.

**Flatten mapping**

Choose the projection of the new structure from incoming fields and the denormalized array. If a denormalized array is mapped, the output column will be the same data type as the array. If the unroll by array is an array of complex objects that contains subarrays, mapping an item of that subarray will output an array.

Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-flatten